# Why does my list go outside the table cell?

Tags: html, css

I have a list that appears to be fine in one table but not in a second when the same CSS is used.

It works fine on this webpage: http://c5d.co.uk/kimmeridge1911.php

But on this page the text extends outside the box. http://c5d.co.uk/infirmary1911.php

The HTML is

```css
.birthplace {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: section;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: small;
  width: 90%;
}

.birthplace li span {
  display: block;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

.birthplace li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "("counter(section)")";
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.birthplace span {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5%
}
```

```html
<td rowspan="3">
  <ul class="birthplace">
    <li>If born in the United King&#45;<span class="rightindent">dom&#44; write the name of the</span><span class="rightindent">County&#44; and Town or Parish&#46;</span></li>
    <li>If born in any other part of<span class="rightindent">the British Empire&#45; write</span><span class="rightindent">the name of the Dependency&#44;</span><span class="rightindent">Colony&#44; etc&#46;&#44; and of the</span><span class="rightindent">Province or State&#46;</span></li>
    <li>If born in a Foreign Country&#44;<span class="rightindent">write the name of the Country&#46;</span></li>
    <li>If born at sea&#44; write &ldquo;At Sea&#46;&rdquo;</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="birthplaceblock1911">NOTE&#46;&mdash;In the case of persons<span>born elsewhere than in England or</span><span>Wales&#45; state whether &ldquo;Resident&rdquo; or</span><span>&ldquo;Visitor&rdquo; in this Country&#46;</span></p>
</td>
```

If I remove the margin then it works fine in one, but sends the list to the left on the first page.

In any event I thought that the table cell should expand to take the text of item anyway .

Can anyone help please ?

I do know that I need a second list underneath which starts at number 3 but I can attend to this.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why it happens but you can fix it by removing `text-indent:15px` from `.birthplace li span`

Comment: Thanks. I know that, but the layout is how I want it to be with the indent. It's how the original text is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should probably check if you put the table in a div. Because maybe the text is bonded to the div and the div is bigger than the table.

This solution worked on my site, https://www.tradebyb.com

EDIT: maybe set the divs or table or list margin-left to 0.

Comment: Thanks for looking. The table isn't in a div. However I have solved the problem by simply setting up a new list with this CSS..infirmarybirthplace {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: section;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: small;
    width: 99.9%;                  I still don't know why the table cell doesn't expand though

Comment: No problem. Happy to see that you fixed it.